# PHP module "sqlite.so" failing to load

Tags: php

I have an email server (postfix and courier) along with a `LAMP + MySQL` server set up on `Ubuntu 11.10`.

I recently started getting an email with this error, and I get it every 30mins on the dot:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've configured PHP to load the sqlite extension, when it isn't available to be loaded.  Find where it's loaded with `grep -r /etc/php5 extension=sqlite.so` and delete those lines from whatever files they're in.